# Correcto uso de ob_start función, y como aplicaría en mi caso?

Tags: php, laravel, gif

Estoy exportando un excel con cantidad de datos grandes, en el `<form>` tengo el atributo `target="_blank"` donde hago que se realize el proceso desde una ventana nueva para poder seguir utilizando la ventana principal (petición de mi cliente).

El problema surge luego de que mi cliente me dice que quiere que se muestre un gif de carga o algo que muestre al usuario que se están cargando los datos, dado que en esa ventana nueva solo se muestra en blanco.

Tras haber leido multiples sitios (Excepcionando el uso de AJAX ya que no es mi caso), consigo una posible solución y es a través de los buffers de salida:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sin embargo no logro entender muy bien el uso de esa función, y como me ayudaría en mi caso.

Agradezco de antemano su ayuda

PD: Uso Laravel...

Comment: Las funciones ob no te van a servir para eso. Necesitas que el navegador reciba algo (HTML con el gif de carga) mientras aún está procesando (lo que sea que haga). Para eso puedes usar la función flush(). Antes de empezar el proceso "gordo", haz echo o print de la cabecera de la página, y del gif de carga. Justo después, haz flus(); así se enviará ese contenido al navegador, y ya puedes continuar con el proceso. Cuando termine el proceso, puedes mostrar los mensajes al respecto, pintar el pie y terminar. Todo eso dando por hecho que no usas un motor de plantillas (se complicaría).

Comment: Hola amigo, no entendí muy bien lo que me quisistes decir, me lo pudieras explicar con un ejemplo de mi caso porfavor?

Comment: No es complicado, antes de empezar el proceso gordo en tu script, haz echo 'Cargando...'; y luego flush(); La instrucción flush() mandará al navegador lo que hayas pintado hasta entonces, de forma que en el navegador ya no se ve en blanco. Pruébalo.

Comment: No puedes mostrar contenido en la página y, a la vez, descargar un archivo, porque ambos requieren encabezados específicos para que el navegador sepa si va a mostrar HTML o a realizar otra acción. Tienes dos opciones: 1-Crear una página intermedia y redirigir a la descarga y 2-Hacerlo por AJAX que creo sería la mejor opción.

Comment: Implementa AJAX ... es la única solución si quieres mostrar una BARRA de estado o  https://stackoverflow.com/a/14677777/17161735 si solo quiere mostrar un cargando lo puedes hacer con javascript y detectar el evento del submit para activarlo y capturar el momento en que finalizar ... para quitarlo...

Comment: @Triby si se puede con json ... y ajax... en via el archivo en formato base64